# Inconsistent script addresses built with cardano-cli vs. PyCardano

Tags: cardano-cli, python

Given the CBOR representation of a plutus validator, its script address can be easily generated with a variety of tools, e.g. **cardano-cli** and **PyCardano**.  However, both tools generate different script addresses for the same CBOR.  How is this possible?  Am I finding a bug in PyCardano?

In what follows I describe the building of the script address with both tools, using an example.  We are going to work with the following CBOR:

```shell
$ cat script.plutus
{
    "type": "PlutusScriptV2",
    "description": "",
    "cborHex": "581a581801000022232632498cd5ce2481064255524e542100120011"
}
```

##### Generate script address with `cardano-cli`:

```shell
$ cardano-cli address build \
>   --payment-script-file script.plutus \
>   --testnet-magic 2 \
>   --out-file scriptA.addr
```

which resulted in

```shell
$ cat scriptA.addr ; echo
addr_test1wrmz3pjz4dmfxj0fc0a0eyw69tp6h7mpndzf9g3kttq9cqqqw47ym
```

##### Generate script address with `PyCardano`:

```python
>>> from pycardano import (
...     BlockFrostChainContext,
...     Network,
...     Address,
...     plutus_script_hash,
...     PlutusV2Script
... )
>>> from blockfrost import ApiUrls
>>> context = BlockFrostChainContext("your-preview-project-id", base_url=ApiUrls.preview.value)
>>> network = Network.TESTNET
>>> script_plutus = PlutusV2Script(bytes.fromhex("581a581801000022232632498cd5ce2481064255524e542100120011"))                            
>>> script_hash = plutus_script_hash(script_plutus)
>>> scriptB_addr = Address(script_hash, network=network)
>>> scriptB_addr
addr_test1wqql5y0gsa3ul0vcmdzmp9zaxz8ak0d3j8yfd4yd73pfh4c6ew25x
```

As claimed, we have obtained two completely different script-addresses, which is very strange.

##### Edit: correct procedure with `PyCardano`:

Following Michele's solution and insight, an efficient way of using *PyCardano* to deal with the same file `script.plutus` that we used with *cardano-cli* could be as follows:

```python
>>> import json
>>> from pycardano import (
...     BlockFrostChainContext,
...     Network,
...     Address,
...     plutus_script_hash,
...     PlutusV2Script
... )
>>> from blockfrost import ApiUrls
>>> context = BlockFrostChainContext("your-preview-project-id", base_url=ApiUrls.preview.value)
>>> network = Network.TESTNET
>>> with open("script.plutus", "r") as f:
...     script_cborHex = json.load(f)["cborHex"][4:]
... 
>>> script_plutus = PlutusV2Script(bytes.fromhex(script_cborHex))
>>> script_hash = plutus_script_hash(script_plutus)
>>> scriptB_addr = Address(script_hash, network=network)
>>> scriptB_addr
addr_test1wrmz3pjz4dmfxj0fc0a0eyw69tp6h7mpndzf9g3kttq9cqqqw47ym
```

and, as Michele pointed out, we have recovered the same address produced by *cardano-cli*.

Comment: The script address is the hash of a larger binary data struct. Even a single byte being different between the two will cause the hash to be vastly different. My first guess is that `Network.TESTNET` is not the same as `2`. Even if these two are the same there is something else different.

Comment: network magic is irrelevant; all the address cares about is if it is testnet (any of them) or mainnet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a quick look at the [PyCardano implementation of `script_hash`](https://github.com/Python-Cardano/pycardano/blob/ec8722f7bc3a309477bcd106601088b880982d9f/pycardano/plutus.py#L802)

the problem is in the input of the function.

The hash of a Plutus script is calculated using the compiled contract wrapped **only once** in CBOR.

`cardano-cli` wraps the contract bytes twice in CBOR for historical reasons.

for that reason it is a valid input for `cardano-cli` but a bad input for `PyCardano`

in your case your script looks like this

```
581a581801000022232632498cd5ce2481064255524e542100120011
```

| 581a | 5818 | 01000022232632498cd5ce2481064255524e542100120011 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CBOR #1 | CBOR #2 | the actual contract |

so ultimately you want to pass `CBOR #2 + the actual contract`

your snippet should then look like this

```python
>>> from pycardano import (
...     BlockFrostChainContext,
...     Network,
...     Address,
...     plutus_script_hash,
...     PlutusV2Script
... )
>>> from blockfrost import ApiUrls
>>> network = Network.TESTNET
>>> script_plutus = PlutusV2Script(bytes.fromhex("581801000022232632498cd5ce2481064255524e542100120011"))                            
>>> script_hash = plutus_script_hash(script_plutus)
>>> scriptB_addr = Address(script_hash, network=network)
>>> scriptB_addr
addr_test1wrmz3pjz4dmfxj0fc0a0eyw69tp6h7mpndzf9g3kttq9cqqqw47ym
```